# Website Laggy on Chrome Firefox but not Safari

Tags: css, html

Here's my website, I used a template for it
http://www.hdilapp.com

I tried it with 4 browsers:

1. Safari
2. Google Chrome
3. Firefox
4. Internet Explorer

Out of the 4, Safari performs the best. By "best", I mean the scrolling process is smooth. However, the scrolling is not smooth on Chrome occasionally. Well, for Firefox and IE, the scrolling is simply disappointing. It is very laggy.

This is my assumption right now: the reason that makes the scrolling so laggy is the way of the browser interpreting my code. However, I do not know which part of my code I should improve on.

My website is around 4.4MB. Is it because my website has too much to load? If that's the case, then why would Safari load my website so smoothly?

I'm not too familiar with html languages, thus, I don't understand the cause of this problem. Please help me!

Thanks :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try analyzing your page here, it helped me a lot optimizing my sites:
https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/

Could be Hardware-dependent too, if you use different Devices for FF and Safari - some of my old Android Phones lag extremely...